# AWS API Gateway in China

Tags: amazon-web-services, china, amazon-api-gateway

We are planning to launch an app that will be available globally, including China and we plan to use AWS for this.

However, because of the "Great Firewall of China" we may run into problems:

1. The app may not be permitted to connect to an API endpoint outside
   China.
2. If we host in AWS Beijing, the latency would be bad for the
   rest of the world.

So basically, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to setup an AWS API Gateway in Beijing that connects to a backend server in AWS outside China?
2. What are the common solutions to addressing this concern?
3. Are there any non-AWS solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your app. In short you can say, that if the chinese government doesn't like your app, there isn't too much you can do. AWS traffic flows through the firewall as well.

You can try to see China as a seperate deployment with it's own data backend. this way even when the Chinese governments decides, that your app allows unwanted things to enter the country, the functionality inside China might still stay up.

If you really want your app to work in China you probably have to make your app compliant. You will probably not have any kind of success by trying to circemvent the rules. The rules (in Chinese) can be found here: http://www.cac.gov.cn/2016-06/28/c_1119123114.htm